# Creating multiple files from a loop in python - [WinError 3] and [Errno 2]

Tags: python, python-3.x

first of all, I'm not a English native speaker and I'll try my best to explain exactly my problem.

I have a csv file in which data from airb&b are recorded. I obtained this list:

```
room_type=['private room', 'entire home/apt', 'shared room']
```

What I'd like to do is obtaining 3 png and 3 csv files for correlations matrixes by looping through the 'room_type' list.
When I launch my script, I have no problems at all for the first iteration (the files are created and renamed correctly), but during the second one python gives me this: [WinError 3] saying that it cannot find the path:

```
'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\uni\\python\\project\\corr graph.png' -> 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\uni\\python\\project\\entire home/apt corr graph.png'
```

or:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\uni\\python\\project\\entire home/apt corr.csv'
```

That's a part of my script:

```
for room in room_type:
    ...
    matrix=correlation.corr()
    #plotting_matrix    
    plt.savefig("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\uni\\python\\project\\corr graph.png", bbox_inches='tight')
    os.rename("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\uni\\python\\project\\corr graph.png", "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\uni\\python\\project\\"+room+" corr graph.png")
    matrix.to_csv("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\uni\\python\\project\\"+room+" corr.csv", sep=';')
```

Could you give me some ideas? I'm thinking about using os.path, but I'm new to python so I'm not sure of how to do it.

Thank you

Comment: try to avoid the forward slashes. Windows doesn't like them.

Comment: On Windows, forward slashes are usually interpreted the same as backslashes, so `entire home/apt corr.csv` means a file named `apt corr.csv` inside a directory name `entire home`. Is this what you want?

Comment: Tip: Use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) instead of string concatenations for manipulation of paths.

Comment: The problem is the slash in one of the room types. A slash is an invalid character in filenames. You probably want to replace this with some other character like underscore (e.g. 'entire home_apt').

Comment: The problem was the  forward slash. Thank you so much!